# django queryset populate a javascript array

Tags: python, django

I need to show inside a calendar the dates that are not available.

I have a queryset that return the unavailable Dates.

```
#views.py
rental_reservations = RentalReservation.objects.filter(post=post_id)

#models.py
class RentalReservation(TimeStampedModel):
    post = models.ForeignKey('posts.Post', verbose_name="Condo Number")
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
```

But I can't figure out how to convert the queryset result into the jquery plugin that is looking for the following array:

```
var unavailableDates = [
    {start: '2015-09-11', end: '2015-09-15'},
    {start: '2015-09-15', end: '2015-09-23'},
    {start: '2015-10-01', end: '2015-10-07'}
];
```

Answer (score 1):

User django queryset `values()`:

```
rental_reservations = rental_reservations.values('start_date', 'end_date')
```

Then you need to return django's `JsonResponse` to the front end, then you should be able to get what you want.

[Django doc about `JsonResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects).

[Django doc about `values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values).